# Repeat function when finished with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to repeat a function when it has finished. 
For Example:
I have a Datatable with the following input data:

```
Name  |  Birthday | Checked
Test1   20.3.2000   Null
Test1   20.3.2001   Null  
Test1   20.3.2002   Null
```

Now i want the function to Take the first Line where `Checked == Null`
Write something to another table and mark `Checked = true`
After the first call it would be

```
Name  |  Birthday | Checked
Test1   20.3.2000   True
Test1   20.3.2001   Null  
Test1   20.3.2002   Null
```

After the second Call

```
Name  |  Birthday | Checked
Test1   20.3.2000   True
Test1   20.3.2001   True  
Test1   20.3.2002   Null
```

After the third Call

```
Name  |  Birthday | Checked
Test1   20.3.2000   True
Test1   20.3.2001   True  
Test1   20.3.2002   True
```

Data in the table may be manipulated while a call the method so `count(*) on Checked` while not work as a line may be added inbetween.

The Basic question ist. How can I call a function repeadetly, not with a given interval but after the previous call has completed?

Comment: Have you tried recursion?

Comment: _"Data in the table may be manipulated while a call the method"_ JavaScript is inherently single threaded - if this is all going on in one place synchronously, you can guarantee that nothing else is touching your data while you are.

Comment: Thank you for your comments Rob and James. I'm not sure if it is better to try recursion or a function that repeats really quickly. Important for me was the issue single threaded so i know that two calls at once on the same line where not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code

```
setTimeout(function, 1000);
```

Was working in my case. I do not have to wait for the function to finish as the other function cannot access the db before it is finished.

Thx for the input.